# skipping double quotes"" while reading into array in jython

Tags: python, websphere, jython

example:

In jython:

(here I want to read the line as  `file:path` by skipping double quotes)

how to do that.

Comment: You should accept the answer once the problem is solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about your question since in the example you did not remove all double quote, but if that is what you want (removing all double quote), just do that:

```
''.join(yourString.split('"'))
```

This gives me:

```
>>> string = '"D:/IBM/WebSphere8/AppServer/Profiles/AppSrv12"/logs/logbackMain.xml'
>>> ''.join(string.split('"'))
'D:/IBM/WebSphere8/AppServer/Profiles/AppSrv12/logs/logbackMain.xml'
```

If it's just the a first double quote, you can do:

```
''.join(yourString.split('"', a))
```

Comment: i have i have to remove all double quotes